# pdf wil not load in object or iframe

Tags: java, object, pdf, iframe

my pdf will not load in either an iframe or object. Here is my code:

```
<iframe src="test.pdf?id1"></iframe>

or

<div>
 <object data="test.pdf?id1" type="application/pdf">
  <a href="test.pdf?id1">click</a>
 </object>
</div>
```

The pdf is loaded dynamicaly from my java code which writes to the output stream like this:

```
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        os = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, os);
```

When i put the pdf in my image folder and link it in the iframe or object it works fine. So the pdf is fine.

What could be the problem with writing to the response?

Comment: Probably your path is not resolved. You have to configure the static folders that can be accessed through URL. Your images folder path must be there in context but you need to add the pdf folder to the context as well.

Answer (score 0):

i needed to change this:

```
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

to

```
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```